# Pegar valor da table com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de pegar o valor de uma coluna da tabela, mas de uma forma que eu pudesse reutilizar a função para pegar valores em outra tabelas.

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas ele não me apresenta nada no console.

**OBS: O valor referente a linha somente.**

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td id="id">2</td><td>Cliente N - 1</td>
          <td>teste</td>
          <td>2017-02-14 22:00:52</td>
          <td class="txt-center pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok txt-error pointer" onclick="updateStatus()"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="id">3</td>
          <td>Cliente N - 2</td>
          <td>teste</td>
          <td>2017-02-14 22:00:52</td>
          <td class="txt-center pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok txt-error pointer" onclick="updateStatus()"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
function updateStatus(param){ //param seria o numero da coluna
  var teste  = $('table > tbody').closest('tr').find('td').eq(param).text();
  console.log(teste);
}
```

então através do param eu indicaria a coluna a ser pega o valor...

Comment: Você precisa de uma linha específica ou de todas elas?

Comment: Desculpe, irei completar a pergunta.

Comment: "A linha" seria apenas a primeira linha ou a segunda?

Comment: No caso eu clicaria no `span` onde esta a função e entao naquela linha ele iria pegar o valor da coluna, a coluna iria ser passada atraves do `param`, por exemplo na coluna 3 onde está a data, o `param` iria indicar a coluna onde esta a coluna q contem data.

Comment: Desculpe-me, não vi que havia a chamada da função no `span`.

Comment: Talvez o que você precise está na resposta dessa outra pergunta : [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397981/pega-o-valor-da-celula-de-uma-tabela-javascript/398300#398300)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, adicione um parâmetro à função que fará referência ao `span`  onde está chamando a função. Eu chamei o parâmetro de `obj`. Na chamada, adicione o valor `this` para este parâmetro. No segundo parâmetro, `param`, passe o número da coluna que deseja buscar. No exemplo abaixo, utilizei 1, então buscará os valores da primeira coluna, 2 e 3, dependendo da linha.

Para acessar o valor pelo jQuery, buscamos a *tag* `tr` no qual o `span` se encontra:

```
$(obj).parents("tr")
```

Após, buscamos a n-ésima *tag* `td` filha, em que o valor de `n` é definido pelo valor de `param`:

```
$(obj).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(" + param + ")");
```

Com isso, podemos chamar o a função `html` para obter o valor da coluna:

```
console.log(column.html());
```

Veja abaixo funcionando:

```js
function updateStatus(obj, param) {
  var column = $(obj).parents("tr").find("td:nth-child(" + param + ")");
  console.log(column.html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td id="id">2</td>
      <td>Cliente N - 1</td>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>2017-02-14 22:00:52</td>
      <td class="txt-center pointer">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok txt-error pointer" onclick="updateStatus(this, 1)">
          Icon
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="id">3</td>
      <td>Cliente N - 2</td>
      <td>teste</td>
      <td>2017-02-14 22:00:52</td>
      <td class="txt-center pointer">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok txt-error pointer" onclick="updateStatus(this, 1)">
          Icon
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: boa alem do código vc explicou, vou estudar seu código e implementa-lo em meu projeto, mt obrigado