# Pega o valor da celula de uma tabela Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[Ajuda]
Preciso inserir o valor do nó automaticamente no ultimo input text "Gesamt" após entrar com um valor qualquer da primeira coluna vertical, dentro do input text "Mundlich" e da primeira linha horizontal, dentro do input text "Schriftlich". Ou seja.. Preciso pegar o valor do index do nó que cruza um valor entre a primeira linha e a primeira coluna 
link: git clone https://github.com/mauro16/tabela.git
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso te ajuda: [Tabela clicável](https://jsfiddle.net/rn1zwy5b/)

```html
<html>
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
               function selecionaCelula(id) {
                    var celula = $('#' + id).text();
                    var linha = $('#' + id.substring(1, id.length)).text();
                    var coluna = $('#' + id.substring(1, 0)).text();  
                    $('#g').val(celula);
                    $('#m').val(linha);
                    $('#s').val(coluna);
               }
          </script>
          <style>
               td {
                  cursor: pointer;
               }
          </style>
     </head>
     <body>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" name="m" id="m" placeholder="Mundlich">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Schriftlich">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" name="g" id="g" placeholder="Gesamt">

          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th id="NUM">#</th>
                   <th id="A">A</th>
                   <th id="B">B</th>
                   <th id="C">C</th>
                   <th id="D">D</th>
                   <th id="E">E</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <th id="1">1</th>
                   <td id="A1" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">A1</td>
                   <td id="B1" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">B1</td>
                   <td id="C1" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">C1</td>
                   <td id="D1" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">D1</td>
                   <td id="E1" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">E1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <th id="2">2</th>
                   <td id="A2" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">A2</td>
                   <td id="B2" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">B2</td>
                   <td id="C2" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">C2</td>
                   <td id="D2" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">D2</td>
                   <td id="E2" onclick="selecionaCelula(this.id)">E2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/235281)

Comment: @13dev Obrigado pela indicação.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela atenção, Diego. Eu editei a pergunta, acho que agora ficou melhor explicado, eu preciso pegar o valor do nó após selecionar um valor qualquer da primeira linha e da primeira coluna é colocar no último input text "Gesamt" utilizando o even do keyup.